# Multiprocessing data sharing

Tags: google-chrome, ipc, multiprocessing

I was wondering how does Google Chrome works in regards to its multiprocess architecture. From what I understand there is one process which renders everything and every page has one additional process associated with it. My question is, if a page loads 100MB picture how does it pass it to the renderer process?

In other words, what is the fastest way to pass (copy?) data from one process to another?

In yet another words, if one process produces 100 MB of data, how to let another process to read it? (Note that the data was produces after the process forked).

**Edit**: If the child process creates the data and the parent process doesn't know in advance the size of the data, how to pass the data from child to parent? I mean, "shared block of memory" has to created by the parent, right? So how much does the parent know how much of space to allocate?

Answer (score 0):

General name for this is IPC - Inter Process Communication.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Now I do not know how chrome implements it but I hope you get the idea. If I had to choose one I'd say memory sharing or pipe but it could be (almost) any of those.